# Django - cache view response for the remainder of the day

Tags: django

So, `django.views.decorators.cache` defines a `cache_page` decorator that will automatically cache the view’s response for you, such as:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 15)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

I'm hoping this is a super simple "yes" - but can this be set dynamically?

So I want to calculate on the fly the number of seconds left from say, `dt_now` (which is now) to the end of the day, so `dt_now.replace(hours=23, minute=59, ..., microseconds=9999999)`.

Is it possible to evaluate the cache page dependent on such a dynamic value?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/decorators/cache.py#L9) is the source code for `@cache_page`. It literally just passes 'timeout' to `CacheMiddleware` to make a decorator.

I assume you can override this pretty easily in your `views.py`, i.e: calculate time left in the day directly inside `cache_page()`.

Comment: This won't work. Author needs to set different timeout to each request, but @cache_page has its timeout set up once when application sets up the views.